# Laravel Dynamic Checkbox error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravelcollective

What I'm trying to achieve:
User can assign multiple supermarkets to a product, and supermarkets can be assigned to multiple products. When registering a product, I want the user to be able to select from check boxes which are populated from a database.

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'summary',
        'category_id',
        'author_id',
        'supermarket_id',
        'gf_rank_id',
        'average_price',
        'photo_id',
        'online_store_path',
        'ingredients',
    ];

    public function supermarket() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supermarket');
    }

}
```

Supermarket.php

```
class Supermarket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'url',
    ];

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products');
    }
}
```

ProductsController.php

```
  public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
        $supermarkets = Supermarket::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
        return view('admin.products.create', compact(['categories', 'supermarkets']));
    }
```

create.blade.php

```
        @foreach ($supermarkets as $supermarket)
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {!! Form::checkbox('supermarket_id[]', $supermarket->id) !!}
            {!! Form::label('supermarkets', $supermarket) !!}
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: `$supermarkets` is an associative array keyed by 'id' with values being the 'name'; it does not contain objects ... its an array of strings

Comment: @lagbox So how would I go about saving the id of that checkbox when create a Product object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain what has been said in the comments:

You are not supplying an object in your `$supermarkets` data because you are using `pluck('name','id')`. You are supplying an associative array:

```
[ 
    1 => 'supermarket A',
    2 => 'supermarket B'
]
```

So you need to change your display code to:

```
@foreach ($supermarkets as $id => $name)
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {!! Form::checkbox('supermarket_id[]', $id) !!}
        {!! Form::label('supermarkets', $name) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I now understand you have to cycle through each key/value as $id => $name to be able to pull the values for each record in the array.